# Possible to intersect this two lists inline?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Playbook:

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list_1: "{{ ( lookup('file', '../../vars/ontap/usage2cluster.yml') | from_yaml ).sap }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list_1 }}"
    - set_fact:
        list_2: "{{ groups |  dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto', 'ontap_' + storage_stage) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list_2 }}"
```

Output i get:

```
TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - fas09
  - fas10
  - fas07
  - fas08

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - key: ontap_p
    value:
    - fas01
    - fas02
    - fas03
    - fas04
    - fas07
    - fas08
    - fas13
    - fas14
    - fas15
    - fas16
```

I did try this... it works but I would like to make it in the one `set_fact` of `list_2` line directly :

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list_1: "{{ ( lookup('file', '../../vars/ontap/usage2cluster.yml') | from_yaml ).sap }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list_1 }}"
    - set_fact:
        list_2: "{{ groups |  dict2items | selectattr('key', 'equalto', 'ontap_' + storage_stage) | items2dict }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list_2.values() | flatten | intersect(list_1) }}"
```

Output I want with intersect between the two variables preferable in the second `set_fact` directly if possible:

```yaml
msg:
  - fas07
  - fas08
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the (simplified [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) inventory for testing

```ini
shell> cat hosts
localhost ansible_connection=local

[ontap_99]
fas07
fas08
fas13
fas14
```

Get *list_2* by indexing

```yaml
    storage_stage: '99'
    list_2: "{{ groups['ontap_' + storage_stage] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  list_2: [fas07, fas08, fas13, fas14]
```

*list_2* must be flat. The below intersect

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list_2|intersect(list_1) }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  msg:
  - fas07
  - fas08
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    list_1: [fas07, fas08, fas09, fas10]
    storage_stage: '99'
    list_2: "{{ groups['ontap_' + storage_stage] }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list_2|intersect(list_1) }}"
```

This can be further simplified

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    list_1: [fas07, fas08, fas09, fas10]
    storage_stage: '99'
    list_x: "{{ groups['ontap_' + storage_stage]|intersect(list_1) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: list_x
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out by myself :D
Want to share my answer should anyone have a similar question.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    list_2: >
      {{ 
        (
          groups 
          | dict2items 
          | selectattr('key', 'equalto', 'ontap_' + storage_stage) 
          | items2dict
        ).values()
        | flatten
        | intersect(
            (
              lookup('file', '../../vars/ontap/usage2cluster.yml') 
              | from_yaml
            ).sap
        )
      }}
```

Comment: I recommend to take the [here given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77746362/6771046) into account. Already the from perspective of maintenance and operation, it should become simplified a lot. Assume in example in 1-3 years a 3rd person is looking at that line, it should be easily understandable, which it isn't.

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your answer so that it could be a bit more readable. At least now we don't need to scroll the page, and maybe it would inspire someone if they have such complex templates. But @U880D's point is still valid.